# What are some good tools for making macros in Windows?

Tags: macros

I have identified a possibility to have an extremely repetitive task mimic'd by a macro. It repeats exactly the same key strokes down a list until the list is no more. It requires button clicks (possibly replaced by a series of tabs to get to the "okay" button) and getting data from an Excel sheet to another 3rd party program.

Can anyone suggest any options that are (preferrably) free? Examples are good, but given sufficient documentation I should be able to code/record the macros with ease on any platform.

Answer (score 3):

Try autoit3 http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/

I've used it for automating many GUI tasks. It has a scripting interface as well as a programmatic interface using C or COM and it's freeware.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response... it looks good!

Answer (score 2):

I'm willing to bet most people will tell you the same thing:  [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).  It's based on scripts, but has a script-generator, and has PLENTY of examples on the [Intertubes](http://www.google.com/search?q=autohotkey+tutorial).

Comment: Thanks, this one looks a bit simpler than autoitscript, so I'll test both out and select answer later.

Answer (score 2):

Try PowerShell !!!